# Virutalenvwrapper with python 3.9

Tags: virtualenvwrapper, python-3.9

I tried setting up virtual environment for `Python 3.9` using `virtualenvwrapper` and got this error.

```sh
➜  mkvirtualenv env --python=$(which python3.9)

RuntimeError: failed to query /usr/bin/python3.9 with code 1 err: 'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/home/sid/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/virtualenv/discovery/py_info.py", line 16, in <module>\n    from distutils import dist\nImportError: cannot import name \'dist\' from \'distutils\' (/usr/lib/python3.9/distutils/__init__.py)\n'
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `apt-get install -y python3.9-distutils`
2. then it should work fine.